# Xamarin forms - Load pages best practices

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want to create a "loader" which displayed when my ContentView will be loaded.

Like this in YouTube application:

[image]

As you can see, when I click on tab button, a loader appears.

But in Xamarin.Forms, I don't know how to do that, because ContentView have not OnAppearing to hide my loader. (And because my loader will be displayed at the same time of my ContentView).
When I click on my button, my app "froze" during 200ms approximately... Not good for user experience...

This is why I come here, what is the best practice to display my content?

Thanks

Comment: Add loader indicator on page. It should run when page is loading. Start background process to load page content in Task. When content is loaded -task finishes- stop loader and load content (it can be hidden/shown). Make sure you run on UI thread when Task finishes

Comment: @YuriS Hello, thanks for your help. But how can trigger "content is loaded" with Views? Check my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266871/navigation-with-bottom-bar-customisation

Comment: I don't see how another question is related to that exactly. I need to know more about the content you are loading to try to answer. Usually components have either events to indicate that or calls are blocking, so if you are in Task it will exit Task when content is loaded. You can use await

Comment: I said that because I don't have OnAppearing or OnAppeared with ContentView, so I can't trigger my function to hide my loader...

Comment: You hide your loader not in OnAppearing but when load is loaded. Side note: if you really need OnAppearing in content view (which in my opinion you don't) create a class MyView derived from ContentView, add function Appearing in it and call it from the OnAppearing of the page.

Comment: How can I know if load is loaded? On YouTube, page will be displayed ONLY if data is present. ContentView is not really good because I don't have navigation animation...

Comment: if you share your project example I will try to find time to look. Otherwise I don't have enough info to help

Answer (score 2):

You can add a loading image and a grid (or whatever you need) within an absolute layout in your XAML, like so:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <Grid ... IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource InvertBooleanConverter}}"> ... </Grid>
    <Image ... IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Create a property called IsBusy in your ViewModel, like so:

```
bool _isBusy = true;
public bool IsBusy
{
    get
    {
        return _isBusy;
    }
    set
    {
        _isBusy = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsBusy));
    }
}
```

Then set IsBusy to false in your ViewModel when your data has fully loaded. This results in the Image being displayed until the data loads, when it is replaced by your grid full of data.

You'll need to create the InvertBooleanConverter converter like so:

```
public class InvertBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return !(bool)value;
        }
        public object ConvertBack (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return !(bool)value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this plugin to achieve the loading screen, check it out  https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup